# Calculate Variance of Binomial Random Variable - 3 Points Shots

Tags: probability

$\DeclareMathOperator\E{E}\DeclareMathOperator\Var{Var}$My 3 point shot has .37 probability of success, independent of all other attempts. (Success yields 3 points; failure yields 0.) If I take seven 3-point shots in a game, what is the variance of the total number of points I score from these shots?

As a total newcomer to probability, slightly struggling with this problem. This is what I have so far :

$\E[X] = .37(21) = \text{7.77 points}$. Figured this is accurate since the probability of getting 3 points on a shot is .37.

I know $\Var[X] = \E[X^2] - E[X]^{2}$ but I don't know how to solve for $E[X^2]$.

Comment: Your expectation isn't correct; all else aside, it assumes that you can only earn 21 points (or, implicitly, 0 points).  In general, how do you compute expectations?  Whatever strategy you use correctly to compute $\operatorname E[X]$ will also compute $\operatorname E[X^2]$.

Comment: I guess I was thinking is since val(X) = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21], do we square each of these possible values and then calculate the expected value?

Comment: Yes, [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3180390/#comment6546390_3180390) is exactly how expectation is computed; but you need to compute the probabilities, too.  Notice that this will also affect your computation of $\operatorname E[X]$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Can I just calculate the variance in "points" at the end and just calculate the variance in 3 points shots made? So I was going to calculate the probabilities in the following manner : for hitting 1 shot, the probability would be ${7}\choose{1}$ * 37^1 * .62^6? I  would follow that to find the probabilities of each value for shots made. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Can I just calculate the variance in 'points' at the end", but your approach to finding the probabilities is correct.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. I meant changing the question from calculating the variance of total points to variance for the number of 3-point shots made. Let's say I calculate the variance of num shots made to be 10, then can I theoretically just multiply that by 3 to get the variance of total points because each shot is worth 3 points?

Comment: Since the variance is quadratic, in the sense that $\operatorname{Var}[c X] = c^2\operatorname{Var}[X]$ for all scalars $c$, you would have to multiply by 9 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\sum_{k=1}^7Y_k$, where $Y_k$ is the outcome of the $k^{\text{th}}$ shot.  The $Y_k$ are mutually independent and identically distributed.  Then
$$
E(X^2)=\sum_{k=1}^7E(Y_k^2)+\sum\sum_{k\ne j}E(Y_k)E(Y_j).
$$
Since the $Y$'s are identically distributed, we may drop subscripts and find
$$
E(X^2)=7E(Y^2)+42(E(Y))^2,
$$
where $E(Y^2)=.37\times 9=3.33$ and $E(Y)=.37\times 3=1.11$, so $E(X^2)=7\times 3.33+42\times (1.11)^2=75.0582$.

The variance is $14.6853$.

There is a much simpler way to get the variance directly.  Since the $Y_k$ are independent $Var(X)=\sum_{k=1}^7 var(Y_k)$.  Drop subscripts, $var(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2=9\times .37-(3\times .37)^2=9\times .37\times .63=2.0979$
Therefore $var(X)=7\times var(Y)=14.6853$.